# JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data when serving the build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express

i'm struggling to fix json parse errors in my PERN app, i really don't know what's wrong with the code, cause it's throwing errors when i serve the build. I send the json response after the authentication and if i check on postman i see that everything is correct when i'm in developing mode.

```
async function isAuth() {

    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/auth/verify", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: { token: localStorage.token }
      })

      const parseRes = await response.json()

      parseRes === true ? setIsAuthenticated(true) : setIsAuthenticated(false)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message)
    }
  }
```

This is the method i use to check if the token is correct or not (i'm using jwt tokens for authentication).

The error is here :

```
const parseRes = await response.json()
```

The server code is this:

```
router.get("/verify", authorization, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        res.json(true)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
    }
})
```

This method use the authorization middleware to check if the token is correct or not.

Authorization middleware:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
require("dotenv").config()

module.exports = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const jwtToken = req.header("token")

        if (!jwtToken) {
            return res.status(403).json("Not Authorized")
        } else {
            const payload = jwt.verify(jwtToken, `${process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET}`)

            req.user = payload.user
            next()
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
        res.status(403).json("Not Authorized")
    }
}
```

I have the same error when i'm trying to do the login and the registration.

If you need more code just tell me, i really need some help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `http://localhost:5000` doesn't make much sense for production build, whats the console showing in network tab for the response? also if it failed you're not returning anything, just console.error'ing which is no use to the client

Comment: I know about localhost, this app will be hosted locally so i was just holding that url to see if it worked, but i'll change it

Comment: What’s in `response` when you look at in the network tab?

Comment: @DaveNewton i've got some html like if there is an error and not the json response i wanted

Comment: Perhaps it would be worth looking at it and determining what the error is.

Comment: I fixed it, kinda, i forgot to start the server, i'm so sorry for wasting your time, i'm so stressed and i was focused on something else when i was trying to fix the error

Answer (score 0):

try add the following header:

```
 Content-Type: 'application/json'
```

happen to me one time and this line fix it

**Update:**
the problem is probably  `localStorage.token` you cant access like this localStorage and can only be by `localStorage.getItem("token")`

and update and add response without the .json() so we can check why we get what you get.

Comment: I'm still having the same problem

Comment: check my update

Comment: I fixed it, i accidentally forgot to start the server and it wasn't working anything, sorry for wasting your time